# I am trying to install prophet library , But getting error .How i fix this error?

Tags: python, anaconda, forecasting, facebook-prophet

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Anaconda\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-o3yl73zr\\fbprophet\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-o3yl73zr\\fbprophet\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-3503otpz' --python-tag cp37
       cwd: C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o3yl73zr\fbprophet\
  Complete output (12 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib
  creating build\lib\fbprophet
  creating build\lib\fbprophet\stan_model
  INFO:pystan:COMPILING THE C++ CODE FOR MODEL anon_model_db8febf10f23d7fa27a62fbcfd7f17b2 NOW.
  WARNING:pystan:MSVC compiler is not supported
  stanfit4anon_model_db8febf10f23d7fa27a62fbcfd7f17b2_3952845139843312099.cpp
  C:\Anaconda\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.23.28105\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

---

```
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for fbprophet
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Anaconda\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-o3yl73zr\\fbprophet\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-o3yl73zr\\fbprophet\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-_iv7s74v\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o3yl73zr\fbprophet\
    Complete output (12 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib
    creating build\lib\fbprophet
    creating build\lib\fbprophet\stan_model
    INFO:pystan:COMPILING THE C++ CODE FOR MODEL anon_model_db8febf10f23d7fa27a62fbcfd7f17b2 NOW.
    WARNING:pystan:MSVC compiler is not supported
    stanfit4anon_model_db8febf10f23d7fa27a62fbcfd7f17b2_8412490456183199120.cpp
    C:\Anaconda\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.23.28105\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

---

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Anaconda\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-o3yl73zr\\fbprophet\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-o3yl73zr\\fbprophet\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-_iv7s74v\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to look here: https://pystan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/windows.html

and install the python windows compiler as shown on the website

Comment: after successful installation of prophet , i am getting this error during import                                                    imported as : from fbprophet import Prophet                                                                                   
  ImportError: cannot import name 'easter' from 'holidays' (C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\holidays\__init__.py)